# oAuth 2.0 Google API asp.net Requesting Token

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, google-api, token

i have a problem getting token from google api, first i make this request to get code from google

```
accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile        www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email&state=profile&redirect_uri={http://pedidostogo.com/Login.aspx}&response_type=code&client_id=519970867780.apps.googleusercontent.com&access_type=offline
```

this seems to be working fine (im getting a code from google) after that i make another request to get token using that code, for this i make:

accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?client_secret={my client secret}&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri={http://pedidostogo.com/Login.aspx}&client_id={my client id}&code={code i get from google}

but when i do that POST request im getting:

Status:400 Bad Request

```
Headers: Pragma: no-cache
Date: Thu, 28 Feb 2013 20:00:00 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: GSE
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT

Data: {
  "error" : "invalid_request"
}
```

can anyone tell me what im doing wrong? thanks.

Comment: Did you use the Dot Net Openauth Framework? http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/

Comment: no i just made a class named oauthgoogle and i use my own methods

Comment: for production code I would recommend dotnetopenauth :) It just works

Comment: do you have any example that i can take a look at? cause i tried this one from [link](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/help/programmatic-openid-relying-party/) and when i put it on my website it asks me for a openid Login

Comment: Have a look at this -> http://www.dominikamon.com/articles/2918/using-google-oauth-in-aspnet.html